# Flexslider random order after animation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to randomize the slide order on a flexslider.  The random option only allows you to randomize the order on load.  I pieced together the code below with the help of this:
[Flexslider Start at a random slide and then continue loading sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916612/flexslider-start-at-a-random-slide-and-then-continue-loading-sequentially)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var randomthis = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.flexslider li').length )+1);
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    after: function(slider) {
    startAt: randomthis
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

FlexSlider supports randomizing slides.
You can use the below code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        randomize: true
    });
});
```

For your requirement you can use the following code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var randomthis = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.flexslider li').length ));
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        after: function(slider) {
            startAt: randomthis
        },
    });

    // **CAUTION** the below code will remove ALL the setTimeouts
    var highestTimeoutId = setTimeout(";");
    for (var i = 0 ; i < highestTimeoutId ; i++) {
        clearTimeout(i); 
    }

    // This code will add a new setTimeout function for randomizing the
    a = function(){ 
        var newrandval = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.flexslider li').length ));
        while(randomthis == newrandval){
            newrandval = Math.floor((Math.random()* $('.flexslider li').length ))
        }
        randomthis = newrandval;
        $('.flexslider').flexslider(randomthis); setTimeout(a,3000)
    }
    a();
});
```

Comment: They do but only before load.  Let's say I have slides 1, 2, 3, 4.  Using your code, if I hit refresh they will now be 4,2,1,3 and stay in that order.  What I'm look for is a random order after load.

Answer (score 0):

here's a working mockup of your code, use startAt instead of after function;
http://jsbin.com/kunizo/1/edit?js,output

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // create function that returns random number
  var random = function(num){
    var numRandom = Math.floor((Math.random()* num ));
    return numRandom;
  };
  // create variable with slides length;
  var slidesLength = $('.flexslider li').length
  // init flexslider and start at random number
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    startAt: random(slidesLength)
  });
});
```